# Convertir pdf a un txt en lenguaje C

Tags: c, pdf

Mi idea es poder leer un pdf y luego crear un txt insertando linea por linea el texto plano del pdf, sin imagenes ni nada por el estilo pero quiero hacerlo puramente en C(no c++) y no encuentro ninguna libreria que sea medianamente facil ya que no me considero un experto en el tema ni mucho menos.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Ya buscaste lo que es OCR?

Comment: Algo, pero no se como implementarlo en codigo y tampoco se si hay otra forma de hacerlo o es la unica para implementarlo en C

Comment: Más bien se tendría que entender la estructura interna de estos ficheros, para poder leerlos y extraer los datos

Comment: pero no los puedo levantar si quiera como un txt, me imagino que necesito del uso de librerias externas, pero no se cual es la mejor opcion y la menos complicada

Comment: Revisa las herramientas [xpdfreader](https://www.xpdfreader.com/) tienes un `pdftotext` muy útil entre otras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el formato que tiene realmente un pdf si inspeccionas el contenido con un editor de texto (solo pongo una parte)

```
%PDF-1.4
%¿÷¢þ
1 0 obj
<< /Pages 3 0 R /Type /Catalog >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /CreationDate (D:20180722014716+02'00') /Creator () /Producer <feff0051007400200035002e00310031002e0031> /Title () >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Count 1 /Kids [ 4 0 R ] /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC ] /Type /Pages >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Annots 5 0 R /Contents 6 0 R /MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] /Parent 3 0 R /Resources 7 0 R /Type /Page >>
endobj
5 0 obj
[ ]
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Length 58692 >>
stream
/GSa gs /CSp cs /CSp CS
0.060000000 0 0 -0.060000000 10.0199999 831.980000 cm
q q
Q
Q q
q
Q
q
12.5000000 0 0 12.5000000 0 0 cm
/CSp cs 0 0 0 scn
/GSa gs
0 0 0 SCN
1 w 0 J 2 M 0 j []0  d
Q
Q q
0 0 m
9574.99984 0 l
9574.99984 13687.1471 l
0 13687.1471 l
0 0 l
h
W* n
q
10.0052244 0 0 10.0052244 0 0 cm
/CSp cs 0 0 0 scn
/GSa gs
0 0 0 SCN
1 w 0 J 2 M 0 j []0  d
Q
q
```

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es crear un código que entienda esta estructura y así será capaz de extraer el texto.

Para ello lo suyo sería leerse el [standard](http://archimedespalimpsest.net/Documents/External/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf). Para de esta manera entender como se estructuran (y por lo tanto como se crean y como se leen) estos ficheros.

Pero si quieres evitarlo, he hecho una búsqueda y parece que puedes encontrar ejemplos ya hechos para extraer el texto. [Aquí](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7056/Code-to-extract-plain-text-from-a-PDF-file) tienes uno de ellos, y puedes bajar el código para que lo puedas inspeccionar.

Comment: Genial, solo una pequeño detalle, si no me equivoco el codigo de ejemplo que me dices es de c++ porque no es un archivo .h , es un .cpp

Comment: En la descripción dice que es C `This single source code file contains very simple, very basic C code`. De todas formas siempre te servirá para ver como leer estos ficheros y siempre podrías adaptar y reaprovechar parte del código.

Comment: Si, claro gracias, solo lo aclaraba por si las dudas.